# Google Pay Integration Pay.js SSL Sertificate Error

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, ssl-certificate, google-pay

I want to integrate `google pay` using a gateway.

I created the `google pay` account with the `url`  information I work in `local`

While trying to import pay js, I get an `error` as in ss, I haven't figured out why yet.

[image]

[image]

The main reason I got this error is because I don't have a local **ssl certificate.**

I am using Spring framework and ubuntu as operating system. How can I define **SSL Certification** in my local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got a reproduction scenario?

It's hard to say specifically what's going on with this, but note that Google Pay needs to be running in a *secure* context. i.e. valid `https`, or with a valid browser exception like `localhost`.

If you're working with a web framework, consider using the framework specific libraries for React, Angular or Web Components: https://github.com/google-pay/google-pay-button#readme

Here are some samples:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/google-pay-react
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/google-pay-angular
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/google-pay-custom-element
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/google-pay-vue
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/google-pay-svelte

---

EDIT: Additional context for working with SSL locally

Have a look at the following resource for working with secure contexts locally: https://web.dev/when-to-use-local-https/

Some options to consider:

- Add an [insecure override](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289?hl=en#zippy=%2Coverride-insecure-origin-restrictions) for your local environment in your browser to treat it as secure. For Google Chrome, use: `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`.
- [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which will expose your local environment as a **publicly** accessible `https` endpoint. The **public** endpoint may be considered either a non starter for you, or a feature depending on your requirements/constraints.
- [local-ssl-proxy](https://github.com/cameronhunter/local-ssl-proxy) which will proxy your application via a local SSL proxy using a self signed certificate. This is more onerous to set up but doesn't expose your local environment to the internet.

Comment: I updated the question, I'm wondering how can I set up ssl certification in local

Comment: Added some extra details about working with SSL locally.

Comment: Problem solved. I made a reverse proxy with Ngrok, it allows us to use https and certificate, it's very simple.